# Can I pass headers to an image source?

Tags: react-native

My image-source is secured, so ideally I would like to do the following:

```
<Image source={{uri: "http://path/to/image", 
                headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.bearerToken}}}/>
```

Is there anyway I can approximate that, short of loading the image into Javascript and rendering the image from there?

Comment: I understand this question is pretty dated at this point, but I came upon it while searching for an answer and yes, you can. It's implemented to work exactly how you have it formatted in your question, although you'd have to account for whether http is correct vs https depending on other factors. https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#imagesource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This capability has recently been merged into React-Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7338/files

Comment: this is promising, however as of the moment of this comment, android feature is not merged, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7791

Answer (score 27):

React Native supports adding header or body in requesting image. UPDATED: See [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#imagesource).

```
 <Image source={{
      uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Pragma: 'no-cache'
      },
      body: 'Your Body goes here'
    }}
    style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

Comment: Cè-zù.  This is new, isn't it?

Comment: How to display octet-stream image from server url?.

Comment: Link to docs is out of date. New url which points to Image -> ImageSource which contains headers, etc. is https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#imagesource

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem before, but Image component does not support this feature right now.

You may try [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) to get BASE64 string of the image url and set its source this way

```
    <Image source={{uri : BASE64_IMAGE_STRING}}/>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I _am_ doing, and wish to cease doing.

Comment: Also base64 encoded images as RN Image sources are really slow