# Load image from server that requires sending headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to load an image from server that requires a token, but I don't know how to send the token in headers of axios or fetch request to get it loaded. How can I send headers with url to load my image from server in my React application?

Here is my image tag

```
<img 
   src={{
    uri: `${activeCoverHash}`,
    headers: { t: token }
   }} 
   alt={i.name}
   onLoad={() => console.log('___DONE___')}/>
```

but it gives me a 404 error. What can I do?

Actually I got that pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47324911/5354341), but it is only works on React Native not React.

Comment: That example is for react native, in the browser you probably have to fetch your images using javascript if you want to add headers.

Comment: t\how can i do that in react????

Comment: @a_m_dev Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079576/loading-image-in-javascript-with-bearer-token

Comment: thank you for that @prakash but its is base64 and needs XMLHttpRequet , i want to do it in react using fetch or axios some how...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can load the image by fetching the image using javascript and then loading it in the `src` attribute of image tag.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`${activeCoverHash}`, { headers: {'t': token }, responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then((res) => {

      let data = new Uint8Array(res.data);
      let raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
      let base64 = btoa(raw);
      let src = "data:image;base64," + base64;

      this.img.src = src;
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
        <img src={""} alt={"Loading..."} ref={(e) => this.img = e} />
    )
}
```

Comment: can you please present a non async await example , please ,please please , i need to check some thing ... thank you

Comment: im getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property src, object is not extensible, it seems that its working , but has a little problem here , please help man , i appropriate you

Comment: the ref solution does not worked but i made it work by saving it in the state and calling it in render , is it good to store large data in state ???

Comment: That should not be a big problem. Though i wonder why ref is not working

Answer (score 2):

Using IONIC v4 and React would be:

```
import React from 'react';
import API from '../api';

type ImageWithAuthProps = {
    url: string;
}

const ImageWithAuth: React.FC<ImageWithAuthProps> = (props) => {

    // Components refs
    const img: React.Ref<HTMLImageElement> = React.createRef();

    // Load data
    React.useEffect(() => {
        API.get(`${props.url}`,
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'image/jpeg'
            }
        }).then((res) => {

            const blob = new Blob([res.data], {
                type: 'image/jpeg',
            });

            console.log("blob: ", blob);
            var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            if (img.current != null)
                img.current!.src = objectURL;
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <img src={""} alt={"Loading..."} ref={img} />
    );

};

export default ImageWithAuth;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this alternative solution which however has no relation with Ionic. It will work with any React web app.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the react solution from @MariuszWiazowski, it works without Ionic however when using `<ImageWithAuth/>` component in several places in my app I noticed it sometimes displays image alt instead of image itself.

It seems the problem occurs when image is already fetched but `img.current` is still null. To avoid it we should save fetched image to component state using  `useState` and update `img.current.src` only after we have `fetchedImage` and img ref is not null.

Something like this:

```
export const ImageWithAuth: React.FC<ImageWithAuthProps> = ({ url }) => {

  const [fetchedImage, setFetchedImage] = useState<string | undefined>()
  const img: React.Ref<HTMLImageElement> = React.createRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}`, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'image/jpeg',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const blob = new Blob([res.data], {
          type: 'image/jpeg',
        })

        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        setFetchedImage(objectURL)
      })
  }, [url])


  useEffect(() => {
  // Make sure img.current is not null and image is fetched
    if (img.current && fetchedImage) {
      img.current.src = fetchedImage
    }
  }, [fetchedImage])

  return <img src={''} alt={'Loading...'} ref={img} />
}

export default ImageWithAuth
```